# Windows Double Click Detection (UseDoubleClickTimer)

Tags: windows, windows-explorer

In Windows there is a way to enable single click mode for Explorer
[image]

For ages there used to be a registry setting
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\UseDoubleClickTimer
I remember it from Windows 98 & Me from several Tweak Tools, it used to call 'Prevent Accidental Double Clicks'. The setting makes sense in Explorer Single Click mode, because Windows used to filter-out double clicks in a single-click mode to prevent accidental double click. As a result it introduces ~400 ms delay for user interaction, before actually launching program or opening a folder. Creating this hidden registry key always used to disable this feature and speedup user workflow.

In NT4, WindowsXP, 2000 despite significant rework, all of this was still the case.

Later on in Windows 7 this setting apparently disappeared and no longer respected, BUT this functionality also disappeared, so there were no delay for user anyway (and no way to enable double click prevention for those who want it).

Finally, in Win10 we have this double click prevention again, by default, but this registry key still have no effect. I can't find any way to disable double click prevention and speedup my workflow. Every click in explorer on a file or a folder (not in a tree, in a main area) is delayed.

What was done: I actually just installed WinMe, WinXP, Win7 and Win10 on a virtual machine. I had to install ~30 tweak tools from majorgeeks in order to find this old tweak (it is available in WinBoos and tweakUI), and then I've exported registry before and after to find the registry key responsible for this. Then I've reproduced the default and customized behavior on different windows versions as was described above.

What I'd like to achieve: remove this delay when clicking on a program or folder.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the standard Windows mouse control option to set the double-click speed?

- Press <kbd>Win</kbd> and type *mous*.
- Select *Mouse & Touchpad*.
- Select *Additional mouse options*.
- Adjust the *Double-click speed* slider and test by clicking the folder icon to the right.

[image: Mouse double-click speed]

Comment: Yes, I did, it affects the delay but it can't remove it completely.

Comment: Have you tried setting `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Mouse\DoubleClickSpeed` directly in Registry? It might be necessary to log out and in again, *without* opening Mouse Properties CPL, for the changes to stick.

Comment: Sure, it's the same thing as doing it through UI. I'm not looking for changing the double click speed, I'm looking for removing the Explorer delay completely, disabling 'Prevent Accidental Double Clicks' feature same way as it was in older versions of OS. The setting you are referring to is System-wide. I'm looking for Explorer feature, no other app is doing that, it is program-specific feature.